при повторном старте бота клонируется кнопка. aiogram python
builder = InlineKeyboardBuilder()

@dp.message(Command("start"))
async def cmd_start(message: types.Message, bot: Bot):
    builder.row(types.InlineKeyboardButton(
        text="Спонсор 1",
        url="https://t.me/+sqYzScols_ZmZWE6"),
    )
    await message.reply(
        'Привет, чтобы продолжить, необходимо подписаться на всех спонсоров:',
        reply_markup=builder.as_markup(),
    )


Зачем вы инлайн кнопки инициализировали глобально? Они так и будут при каждом запуске накладываться

Добро пожаловать на сайт ru.SO! как задать хороший вопрос => https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask
